# FK constraints get enabled automatically + SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

We got a script to disable FK constraints by passing 'D' deactivate 'A' for activate.
Once these are disabled, they get enabled back again after couple of hours or a day.
What could be the reason ?

Script is as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DisableEnableForeignKeys] @PutFK CHAR(1)
as

 DECLARE @IdFK integer
 DECLARE @ForeignKey sysname
 DECLARE @ChildTable sysname
 DECLARE @ParentTable sysname
 DECLARE @ParentColumn sysname
 DECLARE @ChildColumn sysname
 DECLARE @ParentColumns varchar(1000)
  DECLARE @ChildColumns varchar(1000)



    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects where type = 'U' and Name ='metForeignKeys')
        DROP TABLE metForeignKeys


    SELECT * INTO metForeignKeys FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        FK.constid as IdFK,
        FK.KeyNo,
        sofk.name as [Foreign Key Name],
        soch.name as [Child Table],
        scch.name as [Child Column],
        sopa.name as [Parent Table],
        scpa.name as [Parent Column]
    FROM 
        sysforeignkeys FK

    INNER JOIN sysobjects sofk on FK.constId = sofk.id
    INNER JOIN sysobjects soch on FK.fkeyid = soch.id
    INNER JOIN syscolumns scch on FK.fkeyid = scch.id and FK.fkey = scch.colid
    INNER JOIN sysobjects sopa on FK.rkeyid = sopa.id
    INNER JOIN syscolumns scpa on FK.rkeyid = scpa.id and FK.rkey = scpa.colid
    )T  


    DECLARE met_C_Delete CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT IdFK, [Child Table] FROM metForeignKeys ORDER BY [Child Table]
    OPEN met_C_Delete

    FETCH NEXT FROM met_C_Delete into @IdFK, @ChildTable
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ForeignKey = [Foreign Key Name], @ChildTable = [Child Table], @ParentTable = [Parent Table] 
            FROM metForeignKeys where IdFK = @IdFK

        IF @PutFK = 'D'
        BEGIN
            EXEC( 'ALTER TABLE [' + @ChildTable + '] with check nocheck constraint ' + @ForeignKey)

                IF @@ERROR = 0
                    BEGIN
                        --PRINT 'Disabled FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' on table ' + @ChildTable + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                        PRINT @ChildTable+' - Disabled FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'Error disabling FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' on table ' + @ChildTable + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                        --PRINT @ChildTable+' - Enabled FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                    END
                END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                EXEC( 'ALTER TABLE [' + @ChildTable + '] with check check constraint ' + @ForeignKey)
                IF @@ERROR = 0
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'Enabled FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' on table ' + @ChildTable + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'Error enabling FK Constraint ' + @ForeignKey + ' on table ' + @ChildTable + ' referencing '+@ParentTable
                    END
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM met_C_Delete into @IdFK, @ChildTable
    END

    CLOSE met_C_Delete
    DEALLOCATE met_C_Delete
```

Comment: Only for your information, there are some performance tuning tips which suggest not to name your custom stored procedures starting with "sp", as the system stored procedures do, and that when SQL Server meets an sp_ProcedureName, it fetches its system stored procedure before the custom ones. A common naming is usp_ProcedureName.

Comment: What is the question/issue - that you are finding foreign keys are re-enabled without having run the script you've posted?

Comment: Yes Ponies, they get re-enabled with running this script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key will not reenable itself automatically on an out-of-the-box SQL Server installation.

Perhaps a DBA was worried that developers would forget to reenable constraints (a common problem!) and wrote a job to periodically reenable any disabled constraints?

If you are having trouble tracking this down, you could define a DDL trigger on the database to log the times and user names of all modifications (`ALTER_TABLE` event).

Answer (score 2):

"Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."

Since constraints cannot enable themselves, I'd suggest that this proc is being called a second time with something other than "D". I would recommend putting some code in the routine that logs to a table whenever it is executed and to log the @PutFK value used during the execution. I would bet that something you did not anticipate is triggering the execution of the routine with some value other than "D".

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: could a scheduled jobs (Maintenance Plans) on the SQL Server potentially do this?